# Bind IsEnabled property for Button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a `Button` which needs to be enabled/disabled programmatically. I want to achieve this using a binding to a `bool`. Here is the Button XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="logInButton" Height="30" IsEnabled="{Binding IsLoggedIn}">
                            <Image Source="/images/img.png"></Image>
                        </Button>
```

Here is the code being called:

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            enabled = false;
        }
        private bool enabled;
        public bool IsLoggedIn
        {
            get
            {
                return enabled;
            }
            set
            {
                enabled = value;
            }
        }
```

The value of the property `IsLoggedIn` is assigned correctly. But `IsEnabled` is not assigned the value I need. For example:
[image: For example]

I tried setting the value with `Binding Path` and `Binding Source` but nothing is working.

Please advise what may be wrong.

Comment: Unless you assigned the data context to the control then `IsLoggedIn` must be a property in the View Model, not in the View code behind (and if your data context is the View then revert it now...)

Comment: If you change IsLoggedIn after the GUI is loaded, you need to let the WPF system know that the value has changed. Either declare IsLoggedIn as [`DependencyProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview) or implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Then... I think must be so.

```
class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public bool enabled;
        public bool IsLoggedIn
        {
            get
            {
                return enabled;
            }
            set
            {
                enabled = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsLoggedIn");
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string property = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Assign an instance of Model to the DataContext property of your MainWindow. E.g. add a field like `private Model viewModel = new Model();`, and add `DataContext = viewModel;` in the MainWindow constructor.

Comment: Well, it should work. Make the `enabled` field private to avoid that it is accidentially accessed from outside the Model class.

Comment: @Clemens, thanks, it really helps when I set `IsEnabled="{Binding Path = IsLoggedIn}"`, but not working `IsEnabled="{Binding Path = !IsLoggedIn}` for another button, which should have the opposite property to login button.

Comment: `!IsLoggedIn` is not a valid property path in WPF data binding. Either add another property, or write a Binding Converter that inverts the boolean value.

Comment: Upvoted because this view model is pretty much how it's done. By the way, the `CallerMemberName` attribute means you can just write `OnPropertyChanged()` here. For inversion, you might as well follow the advice from Clemens and make a value converter. You're likely to need one to invert booleans again (this has been my experience at least).

Comment: Note that Visual Studio now encourages making properties static when possible (such as when they only access non-member values to determine their value). However, if you make a property static then it will fail silently to bind properly. I lost a day to this one!

Answer (score 5):

Two things are missing:

1. The `IsLoggedIn` property should be in `DataContext` object. In MVVM, this means it should be in the view model.
2. The `DataContext` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so the view can change when you update the property programatically.

Comment: I can't really commit to a longer answer at the moment, things are happening here.

Comment: The OP has pretty much answered it now, I think I'll upvote that instead.